# How do I navigate the lost woods?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I keep getting redirected back to kokiri village, and I found my way to the forest meadow once, but now I need to find it again and I can't. Is there a trick to it or do I just need to get lucky, playing on a nintendo 64.

Comment: The tunnels are always the same (leading to the same places), you can map it in a couple minutes if you wish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways of navigating. The first is to listen for the music cues. The second is to go down the tunnels to almost the transition point. The real tunnel has a slightly different appearance when you do this.

I use the second method when I play, as I found it faster and more reliable. As I recall, the trick also works in *Majora's Mask*.

Comment: The second is the one I have been using since I was 7 and I almost never see people online mentioning it for some reason. If the hole is pitch-black you can safely go through it (it's not necessarily the 'right' way, but it won't send you back to the start). If there is white in the middle, it WILL send you back outside. Then at the end you go right (towards the top of the map, listen to the music if you are unsure.)

Answer (score 6):

It's been quite a while, but if I remember correctly, the music is the trick. I belive it gets louder as you get closer to the "right tunnel."

Comment: I think that works only for the first few turns, and then after that there either is no music, or there is music at all three options. At least that's what I remember from playing 3DS version. I don't remember from the N64 version, I probably used a guide!

Answer (score 0):

Go a little into the tunnel. The real tunnel will be completely black but the fake ones will have a greyish tinge